# NHibernate HBM: Are there default discriminator values?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

In a .NET application using HBM mapping files, an Entity was split into two with inheritance thus creating a discriminator column to map the new classes.
The column is created with a null value, is there a way to indicate a default value for discriminators so they are already pointed at a specific class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case, that your base class is not abstract... *it makes sense to instantiate* - it can also have a discriminator value. We will then apply it on class element

```
<class name="Cat" table="CATS" discriminator-value="C">
```

Check this:

[5.1. Mapping declaration](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration)

example snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Eg"
    namespace="Eg">

        <class name="Cat" table="CATS" discriminator-value="C">
                <id name="Id" column="uid" type="Int64">
                        <generator class="hilo"/>
                </id>
                <discriminator column="subclass" type="Char"/>
                ...
                <subclass name="DomesticCat" discriminator-value="D">
```

Comment: That seems interesting, but the old class was split into a base **abstract** class and two other concrete classes, which I would like one to be the default in case of null values.

Comment: Just think about it... it does not make sense. What NHibernate has for you - is reasonable. Adjust your logic to follow a fact: abstract class... no default discriminator. Each child has its own value, and that will be the default.. I strongly suggest, do not try to invent the wheel here.. it is working and proven concept as is

Comment: I think I may have mistyped, so I'll give a more literal example... Not trying to reinvent the wheel here... I have an Abscract Class (no discriminator value), Inheritante A (discriminator "A") and Inheritance B (discriminator "B"). But since the table already has values and a new column will be added with null values to be the discriminator, I wanted to know if there's a way to point all records with null values to Inheritance A. Does this exists? If doesn't I can performe a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Look, this kind of DB operation is standard. And schema change (ADD COLUMN) must be followed by UPDATE (insert the default). Or with *MS SQL Server like*, you can easily provide constraint with a default value ADD ... DEFAULT('ABC')... Anyhow. That is about the DB side only. The change simply requires both.. schema end data update. It cannot be moved to NHiberante. Hope this helps a bit. Good luck with NHibernate

Comment: yeah that's what I'm going to do. Just thought there would be a way through mappings and decided to ask. Thanks!